# How can I make a background image (CSS) responsive?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image, url

I'd first like to start off saying that I have tried everything I could find on this site and others, it simple does not work for what I am doing. I set a background with

```
header.masthead {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-image: url("../img/image.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

and would like to make it responsive (optimized for mobile), I found one thing that worked but it messed up the experience on desktop (I tried using @media tags to specify resolution but it did nothing).

Any help?

Edit: You can view the GitHub repository at https://github.com/t0091/t0091.github.io/tree/master/home.

Comment: This [link](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) might help.

Answer (score 1):

As you have kept your image as background via css, So there's no way to apply any bootstrap responsive class to it.

What you can do is to have multiple resolution of your background image and put the small res image in the media query like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
header.masthead {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background: url("smallresimage.png") center center no-repeat; /*put small res image here*/
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {

}
```

and put your mobile only stuff in there or switch it to min-width:1000px and put your NON mobile in there.